# Google Maps API - Custom Marker, NOT an image

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Is it possible to use a custom marker that is only text on a google map (that is NOT an image)?

For example, I display a small circle with a number in it on specified locations on the google map.  I only know that I can add markers, with the data popping up after the marker is clicked - I rather display the data directly on the map.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It is not clear to me. Do you want the circle and number to act as a marker and then if it is clicked show some text? How high can the number in a circle get?

Comment: @MiaDiLorenzo only 3 characters (999 is the max).  I don't necessarily need to display additional info by clicking - although it wouldn't hurt... I'd take it with or without though at this point.

Comment: Got it. Now I believe the circled number has to be an image. I know there are unicode characters like this CIRCLED DIGIT ONE (U+2460) but it only goes to 20. Can you explain how you intend to circle text?

Comment: @MiaDiLorenzo hmm..  I suppose it doesn't need to even be inside a circle.  The main point is that it's on the map in a specific location, and that it's readable - so it'll need SOME kind of background...

Answer (score 1):

You could try using an "overlay" as outlined here:

```
http://blog.mridey.com/2009/09/label-overlay-example-for-google-maps.html
```

Alternatively, maybe generating text as dynamic images using ImageMagick would be a good solution: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php